# NullPointerException метода openOrCreateDatabase при перезапуске приложения из IDE

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Сначала я брал данные (допустим, введённые с клавиатуры заметки) из БД в `onCreateView` фрагмента, где это заметки отображаются, но когда проработал функцию добавления новых заметок в другой активности, то обнаружил, что при возврате в предыдущую активность новых заметок не появляется, пока не перезапустить приложение. Я сделал вывод, что это при возврате в предыдующую активность метод `onCreateView` не выполняется и надо прописать код получения данных в `onResume`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getNoteData();
}
```

[Как известно](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/lifecycle.php), `onResume()` выполняется всегда: как следом после `onCreate`, так и без него, потому получать данные во избежание дублирования кода можно только в `onResume`. Теперь код имеет вид:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
    notesDBHelper = new notesDBHelper(context);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getNoteData();
}
```

Приведённая ниже ошибка возникает при перезапуске главной активности из `Android Studio`; других условий возникновения данной ошибки пока не обнаружил. Вероятно, после окончания разработки эта ошибка и не будет возникать, но сейчас надо понять, почему она возникает.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: jp.co.yd.infowajg.ydjks, PID: 11599
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ru.example/ru.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
...
at jp.co.yd.infowajg.ydjks.fragment.InboxTabFragment.onResume(InboxTabFragment.java:50)
```

Последняя строка (из того, что я скопировал и вставил) как раз ссылается на

```
getNoteData()
```

---

**Обновление** Добавил весь код Fragment-класса.

```
public class NotesTabFragment extends AbstractTabFragment{
private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_notes;

    NotesDBHelper notesDBHelper;

    public static NotesTabFragment getInstance(Context context){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        NotesTabFragment fragment = new NotesTabFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.setContext(context);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        notesDBHelper = new NotesDBHelper(context);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getNotesItems();
    }

    private void getNotesItems(){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new InboxItemsAdapter(notesDBHelper.getAllNotes()));
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас `context` null

Comment: Тогда может и `notesDBHelper = new notesDBHelper(context);` перенести в `onResume`?

Comment: Лучше покажите где и как контекст инициализируете. Или замените его на getActivity()

Comment: Как заполняется ```context``` и зачем его хранить в поое когда есть метод ```getContext()/getActivity() ```? Приложите полный стектрейс а не отрывок.

Comment: temq, нет проблем, обновил поле вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Нет особого смысла хранить контекст в отдельной переменной.

К тому же вы его совершенно неправильно используете в вашем случае - задавать его фрагменту при создании экземпляра оного - абсолютно неправильно.

Получать контекст во фрагменте надо методом `getActivity()`

Так что просто удалите вашу переменную `context` и замените её использование на вызов метода `getActivity()`

Comment: В `onCreateView` сделать как Вы сказали - нет проблем, но что насчёт `getInstance`? Кстати, этот метод сделал по [этому](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdgLNfz1PrA&index=12&list=PLIU76b8Cjem54jkj0XtCAp8JqZooY_eBI) образцу.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, возможно я чего-то не знаю, но такого я ни разу не видел. Склонен полагать что автор видео немного не подумал. Контекст - это связь компонента приложения с системой. Пока фрагмент не добавлен в активити у него не вызовутся методы жизненного цикла и контекст ему не нужен ибо он существует в "безвоздушном" пространстве. Повторюсь - может быть я не знаю чего-то, но лично по моему многолетнему опыту - передача контекста в `getInstance()` - дичь и мрак. Да и сам метод этот принято называть `newInstance()` ибо это не синглтон

Comment: Благодарю Вас за объяснение. А как тогда лучше инициализировать фрагмент? Можете дать какую-нибудь ссылку на пример, написанный по правилам хорошего тона?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, достаточно просто удалить переменную `context` и не передавать его во фрагмент при создании.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu контекст у фрагмента появляется после метода жц ```onAttach() ``` поэтому нет необходимости как то с наружи передавать контекст т.к. это будет создавать ошибки после пересоздания фрагмента. Иногда полезней читать оффициальную документацию вместо просмотра видео с сомнительным содержанием, ну или хотя бы иногда поглядывать в нее - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=ru