# TabLayout с отдельным классом на каждую вкладку без заголовков

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Среди большинства примеров о `TabLayout`, которые я видел, у всех вкладок был один класс на все вкладки. Как технически правильно создать `TabLayout` с вкладками, у каждой из которых свой отдельных класс?

Прошу также сделать к решению комментарий, потому что во всех уроках, что я видел, катастрофически не хватает разъяснений, а в документации, по моим ощущениям, много ненужных подробностей, которые совершенно непонятно, как применять на практике (а вот [пример](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) пример из документации, где об интеграции о `TabLayout` и `ViewPager` издевательски написано 2 коротких абзаца).

Базовый код:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initToolbar();
        initTabs();
    }

    protected void initToolbar() {
        ... 
    }

    protected void initTabs(){
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TabsFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // Здесь показвыает предупреждение о возможном вылете 
        // Method Invocation SetIcon can produce NullPointerException
//        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabone);
//        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabtwo);
//      ...
    }
}
```

**Адаптер**

```
public class TabsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Map<Integer, Fragment> tabs; // Ключ - номер вкладки, значение - экземпляр фрагмента. 
    // Конкретно в данной задаче в табах только иконки. 

    public TabsFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return fragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
```

Начиная с этого момента не знаю, что делать (задача - отобразить 4 вкладки с иконками без текста). Раньше делал так как приведено ниже и работало, но в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606014/nullpointerexception-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-openorcreatedatabase-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-i/606040?noredirect=1#comment825746_606040) вопросе метод `getInstance()`, которые ранее объявлялся в классе вкладки, был забракован (не спорю, что на то были основания).

```
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return tabs.get(position).getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return tabs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.size();
    }

    private void initTabsMap(Context context){
        tabs = new HashMap<>();
        tabs.put(0, TabOneFragment.getInstance(context));
        tabs.put(1, TabTwoFragment.getInstance(context));
        tabs.put(2, TabThreeFragment.getInstance(context));
        tabs.put(3, TabFourFragment.getInstance(context));
    }
}
```

**Пример вкладки**

```
public class TabOne extends Fragment {

    private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.tab_one;

    public static OneTabFragment newInstance(int page){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        OneTabFragment fragment = new OneTabFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
        dBHandler = new dBHandler(getActivity());
        BasicActivity activity = (BasicActivity)getActivity();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // формирую отображение на основе данных из БД именно здесь, т. к. после первого прохода onCreate()
        // идёт onResume()
    }    
}
```

Кстати, я указал на то, что в табах картинки без заголовков только затем, чтобы Вы в ответе не создавали лишних массивов, если в них нет нужды, а так конечно картинки вместо заголовков - не главное в этом вопросе.

Comment: Я прочитал пару раз ваш вопрос и так и не понял что вы хотите, в чём у вас проблема и при чём тут приведённый вами код. Попробуйте чётче и кратче обозначить проблему

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня не получилось сделать приложение с вкладками, при этом на каждую вкладку - отдельный класс. Причина - непонимание концепции программного связывания TabLayout, Fragment и ViewPager. Я хочу, чтобы мне показали технически правильный способ этого связывания, но только не так, чтобы все вкладки имели один и тот же класс. Код я привёл для того, чтобы отвечающим не пришлось его писать с нуля (хотя кому-то может легче с нуля, но не всем).

Comment: Самое непонятное в вашем вопросе: "на каждую вкладку - отдельный класс" - это совсем-совсем непонятно. Попробуйте прояснить

Comment: Допустим, у нас есть классы `FragmentOne`, `FragmentTwo`, `FragmentThree` и т. д; каждый из которых выводит содержимое фрагмента (как показано в последнем блоке кода). Тогда по замыслу, при нажатии на первую вкладку должно быть выведено содержимое `FragmentOne`, на вторую - `FragmentTwo` и так далее.

Comment: Т.е. всю неделю пока ваш вопрос остаётся без ответа под классами вы всего лишь фрагменты имели в виду? И на самом деле у вас и так уже для каждой вкладки отдельный фрагмент в отдельном классе? И вопрос на самом деле в том как убрать аргумент из метода? Тем более, что вам ещё неделю назад в предыдущем вопросе рассказали как это сделать?

Comment: Не совсем. Это правда, что решение с отдельным классом на каждый фрагмент у меня уже было. В  том предыдущем вопросе, о котором Вы говорите, порекомендовали убрать контекст из адаптера. Но не всё так просто - на том коде держалось всё приложение и убрать контекст из адаптера - всё равно что вынуть карту из нижнего этажа карточного домика. Потому возникла необходимость заново реализовывать структуру activity-fragment-adapter-dto. Цель, с которой я задал ТЕКУЩИЙ вопрос - увидеть технически правильную базу, которую ещё раз не забракуют, и далее самостоительно развивать её.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у Вы заранее знаете, что у Вас будет всего 4 вкладки и у Вас есть готовые фрагменты для них, то наследуйте свой адаптер от [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html), т.е сделайте, что-то вроде этого в адаптере:

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new TabOneFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new TabTwoFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new TabThreeFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new TabFourFragment();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

}
```

Ну и в Вашей активити:

```
protected void initTabs(){
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        MyPageAdapter adapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // установите иконки на табы
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.first_tab_icon);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.second_tab_icon);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.three_tab_icon);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.four_tab_icon);

        // Здесь показвыает предупреждение о возможном вылете 
        // Method Invocation SetIcon can produce NullPointerException
//        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabone);
//        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_tabtwo);
//      ...
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение! По-моему, очень простое решение получилось.

Comment: Дал Вам приз за более простое решение.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно чтобы каждая вкладка имела свой класс?

Объявляете `TabLayout` и `ViewPager` которые соответственно есть в вашей `layout` разметке.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

setupViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new menuFragment1(),"Вкладка 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new menuFragment2(),"Вкладка 2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Где `menuFragment1` и `menuFragment2` это ваши `Fragment` классы.

пример:

```
public class menuFragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment_1, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);

    return view;
}
```

А иконки можно поставить так:

вставить после:

```
mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
  mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
}
```

и собственно сам адаптер фрагментов:

```
static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за решение! К сожалению, не могу дать приз сразу двум участникам.