# Android: неверное получение позиции в FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

В вопросе [TabLayout с отдельным классом на каждую вкладку без заголовков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608045/tablayout-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) был предложен такой подход:

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new TabOneFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new TabTwoFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new TabThreeFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new TabFourFragment();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

}
```

У меня реализовано изменение надписи в `ActionBar` в зависимости от выбранной вкладки (а на самих вкладках вместо текста - иконки) следующим образом: в Activity определён метод

```
public void changeToolbarTitle(String title){
    toolbar.setTitle(title);
}
```

а во фрагментах в методе `onCreateView` вызывается

```
activity.changeToolbarTitle(getText(R.string.tab1title).toString());
```

Возникла проблема: надписи не соответствуют выбираемым вкладкам. В процессе отладки я установил, что при запуске приложения после выполнения блока `case 0` из `MyPageAdapter` сразу (до отображения на экран) выполняется `case 1`, в результате чего активна первая по счёту вкладка, а надпись - от второй.

При переключени на соседнюю (вторую по счёту) вкладку выполняется блок `case 2` (соответствует 3-ей вкладке) , а когда мы доходим до четвёртой по счёту, то судя по всему, `pos` принимает уже значение 4.

Можно ли на основе приведённой информации сказать, в чём проблема?

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что адаптер при отображении `i`-ой вкладки, создает вкладки `i-1` и `i+1`. Почитайте про особенности `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` и `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: Почитал и задумался: а нужен ли вообще `FragmentStatePagerAdapter `, когда всего 4 вкладки? Придётся опять возвращаться к задаче инициализации макета с `tabLayout`, `FragmentManager` и `ViewPager` - типовой, но по ней информации мало.

Comment: Если `This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of tabs.` – Ваш кейс, то стоит использовать `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

Без разницы от какого адаптера вы отнаследуетесь. Эффект будет они и тот же, адаптер грузит фрагменты, которые за экраном. Соответственно, кто последний загрузился того и тапки (как правило это точно не тот, который видит пользователь), за исключением только если вы выставите максимальное количество загруженных фрагментов == 1.

Если вы хотите чтобы данные были актуальные:
Минимум - установите слушатель `addOnPageChangeListener` для `ViewPager`
и в методе `onPageSelected` - вы будете знать точно какой экран видит юзер.
А дальше все зависит только от вас, как вы по позиции узнаете какой тайтл нужен.

- Или вы отрефакторите адаптер (уберете хардкод, добавите коллекцию
  с генерик объектом в котором будет инфа нужная для показа)
- Или вы обратитесь через метод адаптера `instantiateItem` по позиции
  и получите ссылку на фрагмент, после чего вы можете вызвать нужный
  вам метод в этом фрагменте.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Первый способ привлекательнее. Есть ссылка на какой-нибудь минимальный пример?